# I am unable to create new workflows using sharepoint designer 2013 on new site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I am unable to create new workflows using SharePoint Designer 2013 on new site collections.

When I check for errors I am getting All tasks that need to have at least one outcome defined. And when I check to see the task information, there are no items in the Task Outcomes section.

SP environment: SP 2013
Workflow platform type: SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Does anyone have a solution to fixing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This view will only appear in 2010 platform approval workflow, not the 2013 workflow:

[image]

Please recreate these two buttons and compare the result.

Comment: Hi Julie, How can I go about recreating the two buttons?

Comment: Click the "New" button in the upper right corner of the form to recreate the two buttons, as shown in the figure above.